# Disable timestamp

Tags: apache, rsyslog

How can I disable the timestamp (default template I think)?
I use rsyslog to send Apache `access.log` but I don't want the rsyslog timestamp...

```
Nov 26 14:13:21 remotehost apache: 1.2.3.4 - user [26/Nov/2012:14:13:21 +0100] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2430 "https://1.2.3.4" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1;"
```

Can anyone suggest a template?

Answer (score 0):

### on log server:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 1.1.1.1
$UDPServerRun 514
$AllowedSender UDP, 1.1.1.2

$template MsgFormat,"%msg%\n"
$template ApacheRemoteCustom,"/var/log/manager/access.log"
if $syslogfacility-text == 'local6' and $programname == 'apache' then -?ApacheRemoteCustom;MsgFormat
```

### on web server:

- /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
  CustomLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache2/access.log | /usr/bin/logger -t apache -p local6.notice" combined env=!dontlog
- /etc/rsyslog.d/40-apacheaccess.conf
  local6.notice @1.1.1.1