# How to use more than one template with rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I am using rsyslogd and I want to put messages into custom log files based on their content (using a template) as well as use a custom file format (using a template). The [rsyslog documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html) provides good information on how to create a template and apply it based on the contents/facility/etc. of a message, but does not show how to use apply multiple templates to a single message.

Answer (score 5):

After much searching, I found an example on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569373/disable-timestamp) stack overflow answer of using multiple templates on a single message, but since that question was on a different topic, I thought this was worth its own question.

The solution is as easy as the example below (copied from the answer linked above):

```
$template MsgFormat,"%msg%\n"
$template ApacheRemoteCustom,"/var/log/manager/access.log"
if $syslogfacility-text == 'local6' and $programname == 'apache' then -?ApacheRemoteCustom;MsgFormat
```